# Google Sheets: Is there a way to make an Array for a sequence that grows to a repeat given number of times

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have managed to make this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=$B$1,A1+1,A1)
```

Is making an incremental list in the same column, starting with 01, and on cell B1 I am instructing how many times this number should repeat (up to 5 times per number). So, if I say repeat 2 times it looks like this:

| Column A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

How can I make it an Array Formula? I'm barely starting on Arrays so I'm just trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to solve this with the following formula `=ArrayFormula(flatten(if(SEQUENCE(1,C1),SEQUENCE(C2))))` but you should specify the value limit in cell `C2` to which the numbers must increase, otherwise the formula will loop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(arrayformula(query(flatten(split(rept("|"&A2:A,B2:B),"|")),"select * where Col1 is not null")),SUM(B2:B),1)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qXy-hzWUnsUmAa-8aV5IHOyZABGD_h8ajICLwdyNge8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's either: 
A) when placed on A1 it only returns a "|" symbol when typing 1 on B2;
B) when placed on A2 (like the formula suggests) is giving me an #REF! error, it says its's a circular dependency detected. 

How did it work on your end?

Comment: See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind but I like results, very nicely put

Answer (score 1):

Try `Sequence()` with `ROUNDUP()` function.

```
=ArrayFormula(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(B1*B1)/B1,0))
```

[image]

***When enter 3:***

[image]